# To pass variables set in jenkins pipeline to shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins-pipeline, parameter-passing

I want to send few parameters to one of my shell scripts written in linux server from a jenkins job. Below is my jenkins pipeline job:

```
def MY_VAR
def BUILD_NUMBER
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Stage One') {
            steps {
                script {
                    BUILD_NUMBER={currentBuild.number}
                    MY_VAR ='abc'
                }                         
            }
        }
        stage('Stage Two') {
            steps {                    
                sh '''
                    cd /scripts/
                    ./my_scripts.sh $BUILD_NUMBER $MY_VAR'''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am able to send the value of `BUILD_NUMBER` but not of `MY_VAR`. It seems to me that since `MY_VAR` is set into pipeline that is why it is happening. Can anybody please help with the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to interpolate `$MY_VAR` when executing `sh` step, you need to replace single quotes with the double-quotes.

```groovy
def MY_VAR
def BUILD_NUMBER
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Stage One') {
            steps {
                script {
                    BUILD_NUMBER={currentBuild.number}
                    MY_VAR ='abc'
                }                         
            }
        }
        stage('Stage Two') {
            steps {                    
                sh """
                    cd /scripts/
                    ./my_scripts.sh $BUILD_NUMBER $MY_VAR"""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `$BUILD_NUMBER` worked, because pipeline exposes `env.BUILD_NUMBER` and this variable can be accessed inside the shell step as bash's `$BUILD_NUMBER` env variable. Alternatively, you could set `MY_VAR` as an environment variable and keep single quotes in the `sh` step. Something like this should do the trick:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Stage One') {
            steps {
                script {
                    //you can remove BUILD_NUMBER assignment - env.BUILD_NUMBER is already created.
                    //BUILD_NUMBER={currentBuild.number}
                    env.MY_VAR ='abc'
                }                         
            }
        }
        stage('Stage Two') {
            steps {                    
                sh '''
                    cd /scripts/
                    ./my_scripts.sh $BUILD_NUMBER $MY_VAR'''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> You can learn more about Jenkins Pipeline environment variables [from one of my blog posts](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/jenkins-pipeline-environment-variables-the-definitive-guide/).